# If $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1+x_n)}$, where $-1<x_{0}<1$.

Tags: limits

If $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1+x_n)}$, where $-1<x_{0}<1$.

Find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-(x_{0})^2}}{x_1.x_2...x_n}\right)$$

I used the fact that if $L$ is the limit of $x_n$, I got a quadratic and found out that $L=1$,
but then how do I proceed?

Comment: Hint: if $x_0=\cos(a_0)$ then $x_n = cos(\frac{a_0}{2^n})$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $x_n = \cos(2\theta_n)\Rightarrow x_{n+1} = \cos(\theta_n)\Rightarrow x_n = \cos(\theta_{n-1})\Rightarrow \cos(2\theta_n) = \cos(\theta_{n-1})$. Here since $x_n \geq 0 \Rightarrow 2\theta_n \in (0,\pi/2)\Rightarrow \theta_n \in (0,\pi/4)\Rightarrow \theta_n = \dfrac{\theta_{n-1}}{2}=\cdots = \dfrac{\theta_0}{2^n}$. Can you continue?

Comment: I think I am going wrong, but it is coming $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos[2^n \cos{\frac{a_0}{2^n}]$

Comment: when you calculate $x_1x_2...x_n$ multiply this expression by $\frac{\sin(\frac{a}{2^n})}{\sin(\frac{a}{2^n})}$ and use the double angle formula for $\sin$. Then you will get $x_1x_2...x_n = \frac{\sin(a)}{2^n\sin(\frac{a}{2^n})}$

Comment: Is the limit coming out to be 1?

Comment: @AyanBiswas it should be $\arccos(x_0)$